# How do I make a function for making linear regressions and writing the output into Excel?

Tags: r, function, dataframe, arguments, regression

I am trying to write a function in R which takes in a data frame, makes a model, summarizes it and then writes the output into excel. The arguments passed into the function is the file name I want the excel file to have and the variables that I will make the model on.

Here is the code I have been trying to do this with:

```
functionForRunningRegressionWritingExcel <- function(fileName, regressionName, dataFrame, y, xFactor, w, modelType) {
  
  regressionName <- lm(data = dataFrame, dataFrame[,y] ~ factor(dataFrame[, xFactor]) * dataFrame[, w], model = as.character(modelType))
  summary(regressionName)
  plot(regressionName)
  fileName <- tidy(regressionName)
  writexl::write_xlsx(fileName, "/Users/otakarkorinek/Documents/SOC/Regression Results/new_regression.xlsx")

  ggPredict(change_vs_week_before_stimulus_payments_on_case_rate_change,se=TRUE,interactive=TRUE)
  
}
```

However, for some reason, when I try to run the function with the following arguments:

```
functionForRunningRegressionWritingExcel("regression", "change_on_income", Affinity_County_Weekly.csv, "spend_all", "winner2016", w = "case_rate", "within")
```

I am getting the error:

```
Error in model.frame.default(formula = dataFrame[, y] ~ factor(dataFrame[,  : 
  invalid type (list) for variable 'dataFrame[, y]'
```

Do you have any idea what might be the problem and how to fix it?

Comment: Is `Affinity_County_Weekly.csv` a `data.frame`? Is `Affinity_County_Weekly.csv[, "winner2016"]` numeric or character?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a formula object using the string passed. Try using this function.

```
functionForRunningRegressionWritingExcel <- function(fileName, regressionName, dataFrame, y, xFactor, w, modelType) {
  
  regressionName <- lm(data = dataFrame, paste0(y, '~factor(', xFactor, ')*', w), model = modelType)
  summary(regressionName)
  plot(regressionName)
  fileName <- tidy(regressionName)
  writexl::write_xlsx(fileName, "/Users/otakarkorinek/Documents/SOC/Regression Results/new_regression.xlsx")
  ggPredict(change_vs_week_before_stimulus_payments_on_case_rate_change,se=TRUE,interactive=TRUE)
}
```

Assuming `Affinity_County_Weekly.csv` is the dataframe name you can then call it as usual with

```
functionForRunningRegressionWritingExcel("regression", "change_on_income", Affinity_County_Weekly.csv, "spend_all", "winner2016", w = "case_rate", "within")
```